# Unable to locate pom file in Dockerfile

Tags: java, docker, maven

I am able to build an image (Spring Boot app) fine as long as a jar file is already created.

I do not want to depend on that and instead let maven build it for me

via the Dockerfile itself. But when I run the maven package command, it

is not able to find the pom.xml file which is at the same level with the project

structure where the Dockerfile exists.

Suspect is cos ./pom.xml in this context is not my local folder but within docker container

itself which is why it can't find it. Does this mean I have to actually copy over my entire

project into the container and maven build from there? Is there a better way?

The error:

> POM file ./pom.xml specified with the -f/--file command line argument
> does not exist

Command used to build

```
docker build -t container-name .
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:11.0.10
EXPOSE 8080
RUN apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get upgrade -y && \
    apt-get install maven -y
# following line has issue where pom file not found
# works fine if I remove following line and jar already pre exists
# but i do not want to depend on pre build jar and let dockerfile create jar instead
RUN mvn -f ./pom.xml clean package 

ADD target/my-demo.jar my-demo.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "my-demo.jar"]
```

Project Structure

```
project-name
 src
 - main
 pom.xml
 Dockerfile
```

Edit:

Tried the following to copy project into image. The size of the image is over 1GB!! And still can't find the target folder.

```
FROM openjdk:11.0.10
EXPOSE 8080
RUN apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get upgrade -y && \
    apt-get install maven -y
COPY ./ ./home/dockerdemo
RUN mvn -f ./home/dockerdemo/pom.xml clean package
ADD ./home/dockerdemo/target/my-demo.jar my-demo.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "my-demo.jar"]
```

RUN pwd returns following

```
/
```

RUN ls returns following

```
bin
boot
dev
etc
home
lib
lib64
media
mnt
opt
proc
root
run
sbin
srv
sys
tmp
usr
var
```

Comment: Yes you should copy your sources if you want to perform mvn command from inside your dockerfile

Comment: Another way is to use the jar as is, and run your app with spring boot profile param like : **ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-Dspring.profiles.active=PARTICULAR_PROFILE",  "-jar", "my-demo.jar"]**

Comment: @g.momo Even with copy, it is not able to find folder. The bigger problem being the image size is over 1GB.. See edit above pls.

Comment: After **COPY ./ ./home/dockerdemo** could you do a **RUN pwd** and **RUN ls .** and show us the results ?

Comment: @g.momo Updated above.

Comment: How come your jar doesnt show in / folder ? Please put a **RUN /home/dockerdemo/** and tell us.

Comment: dockerdemo exists under the home directory in container now with all relevanrt files and able to find pom file. But after mvn package, target folder still not showing up. Not too concerned to be honest. Even with this working, this is not a viable solution. The image is over 1GB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about setting a working directory, so you don't work outside of it.

```
FROM openjdk:11.0.10

EXPOSE 8080

# For production images it is always a good idea to remove the apt-get cache afterwards.
RUN apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get upgrade -y && \
    apt-get install maven -y

# Like this you can change the current working directory to the app dir.
WORKDIR /home/dockerdemo

COPY ./ ./

RUN mvn -f ./pom.xml clean package

# I don't exactly know what the mvn command above does with the files, 
# but do you really need to add another file from the project?
# You have already copied the complete project with the COPY command into the container or?
ADD ./target/my-demo.jar ./my-demo.jar

# fine
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "my-demo.jar"]
```

Your ls command is empty, because your current working directory is the root folder in the docker container `/` so make sure you `cd /home/dockerdemo` or set the `WORKDIR` like in the above example. This is also the case with your entrypoint. It cannot find the jar file, so either you put in the the complete path, or change the working dir.

Hopefully you are just building a local image and not a production image :)

And the image size does also depend on the base system.
As you can see here, on windows system the image size is much more increased.

https://github.com/docker-library/repo-info/blob/master/repos/openjdk/remote/11.0.10.md

Comment: This is for dev now but essentially looking at the same for prod too. Bit confused. What's the standard. I will be using this image to deploy to kubernetes ultimately. If I want to deploy a spring boot app via docker, should I copy the project into container and build it there. Or build it prior to image build (so jar already created and only reference the jar file in image).

Answer (score 0):

I think you just missed to add project-name in your path.

try this:

```
FROM openjdk:11.0.10
EXPOSE 8080
RUN apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get upgrade -y && \
    apt-get install maven -y
COPY ./ ./home/dockerdemo
RUN mvn -f ./home/dockerdemo/project-name/pom.xml clean package
ADD ./home/dockerdemo/target/my-demo.jar my-demo.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "my-demo.jar"]
```

Comment: Thanks for the try,. This is not the issue though. dockerdemo is the project name. As mentioned in comments above this is not viable solution. The image size is over 1GB (the project is literally a hello world project). If that is expected.. I need to stick with creating the target folder first prior to creating image.